# facebookads-api exception on fetching lead via Lead() "Resolving timed out after 10518 milliseconds"

Tags: php, facebook-ads-api

I am using the latest facebookads api ver 2.5 with PHP for Leads Ad. We have setup a realtime update for fetching leads via leadgenid. Randomly we are getting time out errors.

```
         $inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
         $input = json_decode($inputJSON, true);
         .....
         //Extracting the leadgenid and passing it to fetchlead

         function fetchLead($leadid) {
          try { 
            $form = new Lead($leadid);
            return $form->read()->{LeadFields::FIELD_DATA}; //array
          }
          catch (Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
          }
         }
```

The above code works well and passes us the lead information except sometime we get timeout error such as these. The missed out lead is however found in csv file.

***Resolving timed out after 10518 milliseconds***

Kindly suggest how can I solve this issue.

Comment: I have inserted this set_time_limit(1000000); and will observe the behaviour

Comment: How frequently does this happen? That error is most likely not a code level issue but the ability for your host to resolve the IP of a Facebook server using DNS. Sometimes this can be because your internet drops, or because you're not using a reliable DNS service.

Comment: It happens once a day. My webhost has its servers based in CA.

Comment: Once out of how many times? If it's once out of thousands, it's probably just some intermittent issue with your network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the script timeout to a higher value this problem has not occured. Marking it solved.